# FMX TListView show text list is empty

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-2010, tlistview

Is it possible show text or any signal list is empty if items count = 0 in FMX TListView.

Comment: Why is this tagged `delphi-2010` (from 2009)? Firemonkey didn't exist in that version. It was first released in `delphi-xe2` (from 2011).

Comment: FMX allows UI controls to own other UI controls. You could try adding a `TLabel` to the `TListView` that is shown or hidden as needed. Or, you could use the `TListView.OnPaint` event to draw the desired text on top of the `TListView` when it is empty.